# Add Multiple UIButton to a ScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, scrollview

Hej guys, i'm trying to add multiple buttons in a scrollview dynamically

so far, I have this code

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfButtonInMenu; i++)
{
    UIButton *aButton = [UIButton new];
    UILabel *tButton = [UILabel new];
    UILabel *sButton = [UILabel new];
    UIImageView *iButton = [UIImageView new];

    tButton = title;
    sButton = subtitle;
    iButton = image;

    tButton.hidden = NO;
    sButton.hidden = NO;
    iButton.hidden = NO;
    [tButton setText:Titles[i]];
    [sButton setText:Subtitles[i]];        
    [tButton sizeToFit];
    [sButton sizeToFit];

    iButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:Images[i]];
    aButton.frame = CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord, screenWidth, buttonHeight);
    [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(whatever:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [aButton addSubview:tButton];
    [aButton addSubview:sButton];
    [aButton addSubview:iButton];
    [multiMenuScroll addSubview:aButton];
    yCoord += buttonHeight + buffer;
}
```

}

I set all my design before this `for`.
When I display my `multiMenuScrollView`, I end up with only the last button displayed.
(so for `numberOfButtonInMenu = 3;` I'll have only the third button display)

it look like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UU6S.jpg

Between the "Explore" and the "Around You" there's two others Button, but with nothing in it, it's kinda weird.
Do you guys have any ideas of what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: so for numberOfButtonInMenu = 3 you have third button display. What wrong did you mean?

Comment: Only the last button is displayed, at the right place.
Actually, the 2 others are here too, I can click on them, but they're empty.

Comment: Have you set the contentSize of the multiMenuScroll properly?

Comment: abyt07 : Yep, everything is working fine, but I can only see the last button (the others are here, but invisible/empty)

Comment: @iphonic : I'm doing this before the `for`. `label`, `subtitle` and `image`, already have the good frame (size and origin),

Edit : I tried it, and ... well, same problem as before, only the last button is displayed :/

Comment: @Vincent'On-arap'Burel can you send me the screen shot?

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA I added the screen in the first post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you add again `tButton sButton iButton` in aButton1 to aButton3. show there're will show only in last view (aButton3). If want to add `tButton sButton iButton` to each button like your code, you need init new `tButton sButton iButton` in each for loop.

Wrong code:

```
tButton = title;
sButton = subtitle;
iButton = image;
```

it must be somethings like:

```
UILabel *tButton = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:...];
UILabel *sButton = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:...];
UIImageView *iButton = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:...];
```

Comment: That was my first though, that the instance of theses UILabel and UIImage was the same.

But then I add the first lines :
`UILabel *tButton = [UILabel new];  UILabel *sButton = [UILabel new]; UIImageView *iButton = [UIImageView new];`
and it was still the same.

(I also add `init]` at the end of each of theses lines to be sure it was actually init,

Comment: your init code is fail because after init You assign tButton sButton iButton with title subtitle image. And note that 'title subtitle image' there not been allocated a gain, there are still old objects

Comment: you need remove:tButton = title;
sButton = subtitle;
iButton = image;

Comment: @Abhinav he did change yCoord to make a difference frame for button in each loop

Comment: OOoooh yeah, Thanks a lot !
I did that because I wanted to fix some stuff before entering the loop (like preparing the UILabel, with the good font, the good background, etc ...)

But I'll set it in the loop for each Button ^^'
thanks again mate !

Comment: But I'm not quite sure why it was erasing the labels/images ... like the buttons were here, I could click on it, I even NSLog them, and it was fine, but just ... no UI showing :/

Do you have explanation for that ?

Comment: @ABáo Yep, got it :)!

Comment: @Vincent'On-arap'Burel read more https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addSubview:

Comment: @Vincent'On-arap'Burel you can see each aButton will add once to scollview, so it's really in scrollView but it color is same with scroll view color, that why you not realized it. But with 'tButton sButton  iButton' you add again and again to new superview in each loop, they will first be removed from old superview, and add to new superView in current loop.  That why they only appear in last superview

Answer (score 0):

No wonder...

You are not setting the frame correctly. In the `for` loop, each time you are creating a new button `UIButton *aButton = [UIButton new];` and adding subview to `multiMenuScroll`. All of them getting added but at the same place. So, in the end only 3rd button shows up.

You would need to set the frame of your buttons correctly.

```
UIButton *aButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:<Set_Your_Frame>]; // Change X or Y value as per for loop iteration.
```

As a side note, you are naming your labels as button suffix like `tButton`, `sButton`. Nothing wrong in it programmatically but they confuse!

Comment: yep', the name are confusing, I'll change that right now ^^'
Thanks for your answer tho :)

Answer (score 0):

vwScroll = name of scroll view
tagsArray = Array of NSStrings. These strings will be the text of labels which will add to scroll view in horizontal manner

```
-(void)setScrollViewWithArray:(NSArray *)tagsArray{
    CGFloat xAxis = 0.0f;
    CGFloat gapBwLabels = 10.0f;
    [vwScroll.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    for (int i = 0; i<tagsArray.count; i++) {
        NSString *tagName = [tagsArray objectAtIndex:i];
        CGSize sizeOfTagString = [self getSizeOfText:tagName];
        CGFloat width = sizeOfTagString.width+gapBwLabels;

        CGRect tagLabelframe = CGRectMake(xAxis, 2, width, 30);
        UILabel *lblTag = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:tagLabelframe];
        [self setLabel:lblTag withBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [lblTag setText:tagName];
        [vwScroll addSubview:lblTag];
        xAxis = xAxis + width + gapBwLabels;
    }

    [vwScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(xAxis, vwScroll.frame.size.height)];

}
```